# Frechet Derivative in General Topological Vector Space

Tags: differential-topology, topological-vector-spaces

If I have a two Hausdorff topological vector spaces, $E$ and $F$ and a mapping $f:E\to F$, is it possible to have a meaningful notion of the derivative of $f$ if the space cannot be endowed with a metric or norm? I have looked at Frechet derivatives, but it seems that they need some notion of a norm, except at $0$, where the notion of the function being tangent at $0$ is based *solely* on the notion of topological neighborhoods.

Answer (score 4):

There is a book by Sadayuki Yamamuro on "Differential calculus in topological linear spaces." It appeared in the Springer Lecture Notes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something that's a bit concrete. The [Gâteaux derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) is defined as follows:

$$ df(x,h) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t} , $$

which requires only a topology on the codomain $F$. The trouble is of course that $df(x,-)$ need not be a linear or continuous map. If you require further conditions, such as the joint continuity of $df(-,-)$ as a function of its arguments, then more of these desirable features follow. This is discussed, for instance, in

Hamilton, R. S. (1982), [The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2), Bull. AMS. 7 (1): 65–222, [MR 656198](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=656198)

Comment: How would the second order Gâteaux derivative be defined?

Comment: Dear user51761, if that's even your real name ;-), the Wikipedia page has some information about that. For more details, the article by Hamilton and the book by Kriegl & Michor are really very highly recommended.

Comment: @user51761 You can find Kriegl & Michor's boook here: [Michor](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The theory of differentiability on topological vectors spaces has a long traditon (the first work that I could quote offhand is by J. Sebastião e Silva (1956) but there are almost certainly earlier examples) and whole libraries have been written about it.  A fairly recent overview can be found in " A convenient setting for global analysis" by Kriegl and Michor.